# sinc function centered at $x=c$ that goes to zero at $x=0$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The sinc function is ordinarily defined as

$$
\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x} x \text{ if } x \neq 0 \text{ else } 1.
$$

I want a sinc function that is shifted away from the origin such that it's centered at some value $c$, and also equals zero at $x=0$. How can I define this function?

Comment: $f : x \mapsto \dfrac{\sin(x-\pi)}{x-\pi}$

Comment: If you write \text{sinc} instead of \operatorname{sinc} then you don't automatically get proper spacing in things like $a\operatorname{sinc} b$ and $a\operatorname{sinc}(b).$ Notice that in the second of these two examples, the space to the right of $\operatorname{sinc}$ is smaller than in the first example: the spacing depends on context. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\operatorname{sinc} (x - c) = 
\begin{cases}
  \dfrac{\sin (x-c)}{x-c} & x\ne c\\[8pt]
  \qquad 1 & x = c
\end{cases}
$$

Below sinc $(x-\pi)$:

[image: Sinc]

Comment: Let $c=1$. Then $\text{sinc}(0-1) = \sin(-1)/-1 = 0.841471 \neq 0$.

Comment: But I think I can remedy this by just multiplying by $x$.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: You make a good point. The solution shifts the function. To enforce the $0$ requirement, $c$ must be an integer multiple of $pi$.

Comment: If you write \text{sinc} instead of \operatorname{sinc} then you don't automatically get proper spacing in things like $a\operatorname{sinc} b$ and $a\operatorname{sinc}(b).$ Notice that in the second of these two examples, the space to the right of $\operatorname{sinc}$ is smaller than in the first example: the spacing depends on context. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can use
$$
\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{c}x-\pi \right)}{\frac{\pi}{c}x-\pi}
$$

But, given the periodicity of $\sin x$, there are other possible functions.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting any function at all is done as follows: Let $g(x) = f(x-c).$ Then the graph of $g$ is the graph of $f$ shifted so that whatever $f$ does at $x=0$, $g$ does at $x=c.$